# A specific height div ->100%

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry if the question look stupid,
I found many question on the subject, but none who help me.

I have 2 div in my body,div1 which SHOULD be 100% height (not working either) and the second with a content which will change depending on situation, I want the second div to recover 30 % of the page, idc if there is something in or not.

I try `height:30%`, I can put 30% or 100% , it will take the height of the content. 
(ps : I don't want to put a static height:px; or position:absolute;)

my CSS :

```
body{
font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
}
#div1{
background-color: yellow;
height: 100%;
}
#div2{
top: 5%;
height: 30%;
width: 50%;
margin-left: 20%;
background-image: url(../image/vent.png);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: will you please add jsfiddle or URL or HTML markup as well helpful in code debug

Comment: add `height:100%` to `<body>` and `<html>` http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/v7Baz/1/

Comment: was looking for something like it , ty @web-tiki   http://jsfiddle.net/v7Baz/6/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">ss</div>
<div id="div2">aa</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#div1 {
    background: red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#div2 {
    background: blue;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 30%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A86Ta/1/

In `#div2` min-height is 30%, so if content takes more space then that, height will increase. If you don't want that, just put `height` instead of `min-height`.

Comment: ty, but it's ok , thinqs to comment :)